# How can I loop "while"

Tags: python

I want to loop from "while flag: ~~" to the end of the code, but when I don't put "break."
Only the last "for" phrase is repeated. How can I repeat the whole "while flag: ~~" part?
I'm really noob ;(

```
pyautogui.click(xxx,yyy)
colorlen = len(color)
for i in color:
    print(i)
dif = 10

while flag:

    pyautogui.moveTo(xxx, yyy)
    pyautogui.click(xxx, yyy)

    index = index + 1
    iter_num += 1

    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    for i in range(left_top[0], right_bottom[0], 2):
        if flag == True:
            for j in range(left_top[1], right_bottom[1], 2):
                rgb = img.getpixel((i,j))
                if flag == True:
                    for ss in range(colorlen): 
                        if(abs(rgb[0] - color[ss][0]) <= dif and abs(rgb[1] - color[ss][1]) <= dif and abs(rgb[2] - color[ss][2]) <= dif):
                            pyautogui.moveTo(i,j)
                            pyautogui.click(i+1,j+1)                    
                            pyautogui.moveTo(selx,sely)
                            pyautogui.click(selx,sely)
                            pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

All the `fors` and the `while` loop are necesseraly repeated while the `flag` value is non empty.

If not, that means that something in your indented `fors` is looping on itself and "blocking" something.

Plus, your second `if flag == True` seems useless unless the flag value can be changed between your two ifs.

So check if something in your while loop isn't blocking the loop.

The fastest way to be sure is to log or print in while beginning

Comment: "flag" value is "true" 
but still the last for phrase is repeated

Comment: If the last for is repeated, that means all the items above are repeated too so the while loop is perfectly fine

Sorry but I don't understand nor your problem, nor your what you are trying to do with this code